# normalized accumulation distribution

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, normal-distribution

I am looking for a way to take an accumulation/distribution indicator and normalize it
so I can compare a bunch of stocks with stock prices that have no relationship with each other.
  EDIT: This would be straightforward on interday data, but the problem is with intraday data:  you can't get an intraday normalized volume measure, because the volume is always skewed where there is huge volume in the first and last half out, and *relatively* meaningless volume otherwise.

What I am currently doing is dividing the different AD measures by 1,000 and then capping at +/-80 anything above/below that:

```
closeVsLow = (close - low) ;
closeVsHigh = (high - close) ;
closeVsOpen = (close - open) ;
myrange = (high - low) ;
myVolume = volume;

AD= ((closeVsLow - closeVsHigh) / myrange) * volume;
pvalue = acdOne / 1000;
if (pvalue > 80) then pValue = 80;
if (pvalue < -80) then pValue = -80;
```

Is there a better way of normalizing this?

Comment: Couldn't you just look at the *CLV*? That's the `AD` you have above without the `volume` component. Every stock will thus be in the same range of -1 to +1.

Comment: You're right about the CLV, but in this case the volume is the most important piece.  This is an intr-day indicator, and AD is the only intra-day volume indicator that is actually useful. Other intraday volume measures are useless..they just show huge volume beginning/end of day, and relatively nothing happen in between.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well, one part of your analytic is already *normalized* (`(closeVsLow - closeVsHigh) / myrange`), but not the other (`volume`). 
If you just aim to compare the values of `AD` from any stock with the other, why not normalizing `volume`by the *usual daily volume* (median of the daily volume) of the stock during the last 60 days?

Moreover, if you really want to detect *outliers* in terms of relative positioning of open, high, low and close, I suggest you read the following paper by Garman and Klass: [On the Estimation of Security Price Volatility from Historical Data](http://www.fea.com/resources/a_estimation_of_security_price.pdf).

Of course the volume will not be taken into account (they just use a diffusive assumption on the price). But if you *consider that volume should be homogenous to time* in usual conditions, then you can extract from their paper an interesting theoretical statistic on how *normal* is the value of the conjunction of (open,high,low,close,volume). There is a paper by Jemery Large: [Estimating Quadratic Variation When Quoted Prices Change by a Constant Increment](http://www.uclouvain.be/cps/ucl/doc/core/documents/Large.pdf) that could be useful to read too.

Comment: Thanks for your post.  But I left out an important piece of information:  This measure is an intraday measure only.  I corrected my post.